# Using 2011 iMac 27" as second monitor with 2017 iMac 27"

Tags: display, imac

I purchased a 2017 iMac 27" Retina 5K running High Sierra.  I have an older 2011 iMac 27" also running High Sierra.  I want to connect the two so the the 2017 model is the host and the 2011 is the second monitor (extended mode).  I have a Thunderbolt cable, and connected one end to the 2011 and the other to a Thunderbolt 3 (C) adapter and then into the 2017 iMac. I then pressed Command + F2 to start Target Display Mode.  Unfortunately nothing works.  Regardless of which iMac I try to use as the host I can never get the desired result.  I was told the Retina 5K model won't support TDM, but I had a chat session today with Apple and the tech made it seem that it would work.  Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: Thank you Steve Chambers.  The link was very helpful.

Comment: Make sure you are using the original wireless keyboard that came with the 2011 iMac, when pressing Command + F2.